# What element was clicked using OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a ListView that uses a custom adapter. The layout that the adapter inflates contains one ImageView and two TextViews. I have set an `OnItemClickListener` to the list. In the `onItemClick` method I receive the position of the ListView entry and the ListView entry as a View, which in my case is type of LinearLayout.

What I want is to know if the user hit the ImageView. How do I achieve this?

I thought this would work, but the `view` parameter in this method is the ListView entry.

```
l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println(view.getClass().getName());
    }
});
```

I could add an `View.OnClickListener` for the ImageView, but this way I can't get the position of the parent element. Or can I?

Comment: if your not using a layout use setId() and getId() methods when you make your view's in code, setId() when you make it and view.getID() in your OnItemClickListener

Comment: Great! Please, post this as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your not using a layout use setId() and getId() methods when you make your view's in code, setId() when you make it and view.getId() in your OnItemClickListener